# UItabbarController problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app in which have 3 tabBarController.
I set the custom tabBarController in appDelegate file home, contact and setting tab.

When I pressed 2nd tab there are 3 buttons on the page. Any of these buttons pressed it navigate to 1st tab as I write code

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

It's work for me fine. It navigate to first page but it show last visited view controller in 1st tab, as I need 1st tab 1st view mean root view.

please help me 
thanx in advance

Comment: iPhone SDk tools give that as by default. if you have navigate to the second view of the firstTab bar then while come again to the firstTab bar it will show you the second (last visited view). If u want to Show the First view of the FirstTabBar every time while clicking on it. Then you have to custom code for it. All The Best for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your button's target

```
[[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

Let me know if that works for you.